# c89 and POSIX at the same time

Tags: c, posix

Is it possible to use POSIX functions even in strict std=c89? When I try to compile executable on Linux in strict ANSI C mode, both gcc and clang know nothing about functions like `readlink` or `realpath`, though headers are included. Since I have to use POSIX functions even in ANSI C mode, I'm looking for way to do it. I've thought about `dlsym`, but I don't know which library I'll have to open. Such calls are surrounded with #ifdef's, so they won't rise an alarm on the other system. Cross-platform solution needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  You're asking if you can somehow treat POSIX functions as if they were standard C functions.  Well... no, because they're not standard C functions and you won't have them on other platforms. By using POSIX functions your code is no longer able to be compiled by any C compiler on any platform. There are of course alternatives, like cygwin on Windows, but you're going to have to plan for that.

Comment: I understand the root of the problem; I'm just want to know if some way exists to use such functions dynamically.

Comment: I mean... they either exist when compiling or they don't.  That's why things like cygwin exist.

Comment: C89 is a language and Posix is a library written in that language... what's the question?

Comment: Such calls are done for POSIX systems and the corresponding system-specific functions are surrounded with #ifdef sections. On Windows I use their own API. I'm just writing a set of function wrappers to improve cross-platformness of the library.

Comment: @kerrek: yep, but C headers doesn't include POSIX function declarations in C89 mode.

Comment: @ghostmansd: Not quite. You mean that "the C standard library headers" don't include Posix. Of course. They also don't include an XML parser or an MP3 player. Yet those things can be written in C. Just include the headers from whatever libraries you need, including Posix.

Comment: i.e. I can't just write `readlink(path, buf, size)` after including the necessary header required by POSIX. gcc and clang just see neither function declarations nor implementations.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Some of the non-C-standard functions specified by POSIX are declared in C-standard header files. For example, `fdopen` is declared in `<stdio.h>`. A conforming ISO C implementation may not declare `fopen` in `<stdio.h>`. There may be a macro you can define to enable POSIX even in `-std=c89` mode.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Right, a Posix system *adds* things to C (e.g. new restrictions such as `CHAR_BIT == 8`, and `fdopen`). But I'm not sure how that relates to the question (mostly because I don't quite understand the question).

Comment: You ask for a cross platform solution.  Well, that makes no sense.  You would need to provide the requisite functions, but your code will never truly be cross platform if you rely on POSIX functions, just as it wouldn't be if you relied on Windows functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: My point is that strict C89/C90 compliance and POSIX compliance are inconsistent. (BTW, `CHAR_BIT==8` is perfectly consistent with both ISO C and POSIX. Added restrictions don't break ISO C conformance; added functions in standard headers do.)

Comment: Ohh, is your question "Can I have a Posix system when I don't have a Posix system"? E.g. a Posix implementation for Windows?

Comment: @kerrek: perhaps I've formulated it wrong. Here I wanted to say that this code must be able to run on every POSIX platform, not only Windows, i.e. I don't want to use e.g. Linux-specific hacks (or at least I need to collect such hacks for other common POSIX systems). Non-POSIX, as I've told above, use #ifdef and their own functions.

Comment: @ghostmansd: Well, just stick to standard C then? That's "portable", in a sense... of course that means you can't have a file system, since C doesn't know about file systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for "feature-test macros". See [the Single Unix Specification, Issue 6: System Interfaces Chapter 2.2, "The Compilation Environment"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html#tag_02_02)

Edit:

To quote that page:

> The _POSIX_C_SOURCE Feature Test Macro
>
> A POSIX-conforming application should ensure that the feature test macro
>   _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined before inclusion of any header.

GCC and clang currently define _POSIX_C_SOURCE for you by default unless one of c89, c99, c11, or any behaviorally equivalent string is passed to the compiler's -std option.

Additionally:

> The _XOPEN_SOURCE Feature Test Macro
>
> An XSI-conforming application should ensure that the feature test macro
>   _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined with the value 600 before inclusion of any header.
>   This is needed to enable the functionality described in The _POSIX_C_SOURCE
>   Feature Test Macro and in addition to enable the XSI extension.

In other words, to guarantee your program (a.k.a. application) can use POSIX, either `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L` before any header is included or pass the `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L` option to the compiler. For the XSI functionality, you must define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to a value of 600.

There is also a newer version of the Single Unix Specification — Issue 7. [Very similar text can be found in Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01_01). The only real differences with respect to the text above are the numbers for _POSIX_C_SOURCE and _XOPEN_SOURCE have been changed.

Answer (score 3):

At least when a combination of gcc and glibc on linux, you can turn on non standard functions (e.g. those defined by posix) with `#define`'s , see man [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

e.g. `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`  before including any header files, or by adding it to the compiler arguments:

```
gcc -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L ...
```